# Automaticly logon on and logoff

Tags: windows-vista, remote-desktop

I use terminal services to manage a vista machines on a domain-less lan. After I am done with that session I would like Vista to re-login to the previous account.

How do I pull this off?

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't. I recall a similar question from SO.

But as it's Vista it should always work in fast user switching mode and lock the current user's session while you log on - after you log off, that user can unlock/switch to his session again, right?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need VNC instead of Remote Desktop?

This logs you in as the currently logged on user (think screen-sharing)

Then you can use the "runas" command to get admin for specific operations if you need it.